# how to make a custom response sample in drf-yasg

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

drf-yasg for automatic documentation generation
Are there any ways to make a custom response sample in the form of
{
"data" : {
"key": "value",
...
}
}
is now displayed like this:
{
"key": "value",
...
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from drf_yasg import openapi

response_schema_dict = {
"201": openapi.Response(
    description="Htpp 201 description",
    examples={
        "application/json": {
            "key": "value",
        }
    }
),
"500": openapi.Response(
    description="Htpp 500 description",
    examples={
        "application/json": {
            "key_1": "error message 1",
            "key_2": "error message 2",
        }
    }
),
}

class Location(APIView):
@swagger_auto_schema(
    responses=response_schema_dict
)
def get(self, request):
    pass
```